# Hide password in dmenu

Tags: security, password, dmenu

I'm new to dmenu. I'm trying to run programs which need `sudo` permission with dmenu. I've followed [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/dmenu/comments/1xxszr/run_programs_as_root_through_dmenu/). So I have script `./dpass` in my `bin` folder which says:

```
#!/bin/bash
dmenu -p "$1" <&- && echo
```

I've also run the command:

```
$ export SUDO_ASKPASS=/home/username/bin/dpass
```

So now I have a script in my `bin` folder called `shutdown`. It says:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -A shutdown -h now
```

When I try to run it through dmenu, it does ask me for my password, but the problem is that when I type the password the password is not hidden. I find this really insecure since anyone can see my password. Is there anyway to hide passwords in dmenu?

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `&& echo` from the end of the call to `dmenu`:

```
#!/bin/bash
dmenu -p "$1" <&-
```

This should disable the echoing of what the user is typing into `dmenu`. This method is covered in this blog post titled: [Enter passwords from dmenu](https://ncoop.github.io/2017/01/02/enter-passwords-from-dmenu).

*excerpt*

> ```
> $ cat dpass
> #! /bin/sh
>
> # shellcheck disable=2046
> caller="$(ps -o comm= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $$))"
> prompt="${1:-[$caller]}"
> promptfg=black promptbg=red hidden=white
> font="Liberation Sans-20:Bold"
>
> dmenu -p "$prompt" -fn "$font" \
>   -nf "$hidden" -nb "$hidden" -sf "$promptfg" -sb "$promptbg" <&-
> ```
>
> 1. It sets the prompt (red part) to the calling application, if no args were passed. So the user always gets a prompt of some kind.
> 2. It removes the trailing `&& echo` statement, so it works on other password handlers.

Comment: I have removed the echo from dpass but it is still not working

Comment: @eddard.stark - can you show us some output from this?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Fuseteam](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/149714/fuseteam), I wrote a script called stprompt:

```
#!/bin/bash

prompt="$1"
answer=$(st -o "-" -g 100x5 -c st-prompt sh -c "echo -n '$prompt: '; read -s ANSWER; echo \$ANSWER")
echo "${answer#*: }" | tr -d '\r'
```

This script prompts the user, hides the input, and will output the response.

For your specific case, you could use this script in this manner:

```
sudopgm==$(echo "${options[@]}" | dmenu -i -p 'Programs that need sudo: ')
SUDO_ASKPASS=$(stprompt "sudo pass") sudo -A $sudopgm
```

[image]
[image]

There's more information about how I use `stprompt` in my [dotfiles readme](https://github.com/jbh/dotfiles#stprompt), and an example usage in my [dmenu_ibmicmd](https://github.com/jbh/dotfiles/blob/master/.local/bin/dmenu_ibmicmd) script.

As Fuseteam said, st is a terminal. You can replace it with your favorite terminal.

Answer (score 0):

a work around could be a script named say `dterm` that runs this:

```
#!/bin/bash
command="$@";st -- $command
```

that way when you run `dterm sudo command` it'll pop up a terminal for password input

as a added bonus you can also run any terminal application throught dmenu

p.s.
st is a terminal it can be replace with any terminal that accepts the -e or -- argument

p.p.s this assumes you can execute your script through dmenu